# cycling through background colors with javascript

Tags: javascript, background

Can anyone tell me why the following code might not cycle through the array of colors defined here:

```
var colors = ["white", "yellow", "orange", "red"];
```

and here is the line of code in question:

```
setInterval(function(){
          currElm.style.background = colors[(nextColor++)%(colors.length)]);
      }, 500);
```

It seems like that should work and I've seen several examples where code just like this produced a color cycling effect. Does anyone see a problem with the above (or below) code?

Whole function(a work in progress):

```
function setHighlight(elmId, index, songLength){
//alert("called set highlight, params are " + elmId + " " + index + " " + songLength);
var colors = ["white", "yellow", "orange", "red"];
var nextColor = 0;
if(index < 10)
    index = "000" + (index);
  else if (index < 100)
    index = "000" + (index);
  else if(index < 1000)
    index = "0" + (index);
  if(index >= 1000)
    index = index;
//alert("called set highlight, params are " + elmId + " " + index + " " + songLength);

//this will be useful for finding the element but pulsate will not work, need to       research animations in javascript

var mainElm = document.getElementById('active_playlist');
var elmIndex = "";

for(var currElm = mainElm.firstChild; currElm !== null; currElm = currElm.nextSibling){
  if(currElm.nodeType === 1){

  var elementId = currElm.getAttribute("id");

  if(elementId.match(/\b\d{4}/)){

    elmIndex = elementId.substr(0,4);
    alert(currElm.getAttribute('id'));

    if(elmIndex == index){
        setInterval(function(){
          currElm.style.background = colors[(nextColor++)%(colors.length)]);
      }, 500);
    }
  }
}
}//end for

}
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: fixed the extra parenthesis, still not working. I already have a style assigned to the element, could that be a source of the problem?

Comment: ok, firebug said currElm is null, but I don't understand how that can be. I know it enters the "if(elmIndex == index){" section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of different things.  First, it looks like you are matching elements whose ids contain a space followed by 4 digits.  I don't think that spaces are allowed in ids.  I'd really like to see the HTML for the elements that should be matched.  Second, I think you want to assign currElm to a new variable that will be captured in your setInterval handler.  If you don't, I think it may always refer to the last element matched instead of each element matched.

```
for(var currElm = mainElm.firstChild; currElm !== null; currElm = currElm.nextSibling){

  if(currElm.nodeType === 1){

    var elementId = currElm.getAttribute("id");

    if(elementId.match(/\b\d{4}/)){

      elmIndex = elementId.substr(0,4);
      alert(currElm.getAttribute('id'));

      if(elmIndex == index){
          var that = currElm;
          setInterval(function(){
              that.style.background = colors[(nextColor++)%(colors.length)];
          }, 500);
      }
    }
  }

}//end for
```

**EDIT** Also fix the extra parenthesis in the interval handler.

Comment: It should only match one element, I'm trying to highlight a single row in a table. I know it finds the correct element.Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error, extra right parenthesis `')'` at end of line:

```
currElm.style.background = colors[(nextColor++)%(colors.length)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the extra right parenthesis as well!

But the nextColor variable is already initialized to zero, right after the colors array.

This is a job for Firebug.  You can set the breakpoint right before you get to the setInterval call, and test the various variables that are in the setInterval's anonymous function.